# Agrupar o evitar datos duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenación, concat

Estoy con un problema que me tiene loco. Tengo 3 tablas, a las cuales les realizo un left join a cada una, parecido a esto:

```
SELECT t1.Cod_cliente, t2.Rut, t2.Razon_social, concat(t3.Nombre,' ',t3.Apellido) as Contacto
FROM venta_productos as t1
LEFT JOIN Companias as t2
   ON t1.Cod_cliente = t2.Codigo
LEFT JOIN Contacto_cliente as t3
   ON t3.Id_compania = t2.Id
```

El asunto es que tengo muchos registros duplicados para Contacto, y la idea es que solo aparezca uno. Este un ejemplo de como queda el resultado de la query:

```
| Cod_cliente | Rut        | Razon_social | Contacto        |
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
| 123456      | 17000000-0 | Empresa 1    | Felipe Gonzalez |
| 123456      | 17000000-0 | Empresa 1    | Felipe Gonzalez |
| 456789      | 12000000-0 | Empresa 2    | Jose Hernandez  |
```

Y como necesito que quede, no habiendo duplicados para la columna Contacto, que esta concatenada

```
| Cod_cliente | Rut        | Razon_social | Contacto        |
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----------------|
| 123456      | 17000000-0 | Empresa 1    | Felipe Gonzalez |
| 456789      | 12000000-0 | Empresa 2    | Jose Hernandez  |
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, y de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Si todo el registro está duplicado (el cod_cliente, el rut, etc.), te recomiendo hacer un GROUP BY y usar uno de esos campos que, supongo, están indexados. NUNCA hacerlo por el campo resultado del CONCAT para no tener que esperar minutos a que termine :)

Comment: Es que ahi va el detalle, ya que el campo que me arroja los valores duplicados es justamente el de Contacto, el cual realizo la concatenacion, porque los demas no hay problemas que esten duplicados.
En resumen necesito todos los contactos para las empresas con su rut, razon social y codigo cliente.

Comment: Agrega un `distinct` en el select.

Comment: Es decir, puede haber un mismo contacto con dos rut-razonSocial y cod_cliente diferentes... y quieres dejar sólo uno? Seguro? No pierdes info así? Y pues, como te dicen, puedes hacer distinct, pero se va a tardar...

Comment: Probe con `distinct` antes de publicar aca y no sirvio.
La idea es, se pueden repetir el rut, la razon social y el codigo de cliente, pero no se puede repetir el contacto. Pense en hacer un `group by` a `t3.Nombre`, que es parte del concat que hice, pero no me dejo hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Envuelve la consulta y agrupa los registros.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t1.cod_cliente, 
               t2.rut, 
               t2.razon_social, 
               Concat(t3.nombre, ' ', t3.apellido) AS Contacto 
        FROM   venta_productos AS t1 
               LEFT JOIN companias AS t2 
                      ON t1.cod_cliente = t2.codigo 
               LEFT JOIN contacto_cliente AS t3 
                      ON t3.id_compania = t2.id) 
GROUP  BY cod_cliente, rut, razon_social, contacto
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado! Esta opción me sirvio!